# Aplicativo encerra ao iniciar, erro ocorre apenas no Android 9.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Eae pessoal, tenho um aplicativo que funciona normalmente em todas as versões do Android, porém no Android 9.0 (Pie) inicia tudo normal exibindo o Splash Screen mas quando vai para a MainActivity o aplicativo fecha e não exibe nenhuma mensagem de erro, já tentei de tudo mas nada funciona, necessito da ajuda de vocês.

```
    //MainActivity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TabLayout tabLayout = null;
private ViewPager viewPager = null;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    //setting the tabs title
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Ao Vivo"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Notícias"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("WebTV"));

    //setup the view pager
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new app.com.portalcentrooeste.adapters.PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Tem chamado alguma activity fora da activity principal?

Comment: Não, apenas chamo as Frames do TabLayout .

Comment: Olha no logcat. Com certeza terá a stack do erro lá.